# Creating an android app using twitter api, the control is not going in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, twitter

Here is the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "hay i am working till here");

    new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "hay i reached till here");
                twitter = new Twitter("student", "password");
                twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
                twitter.setStatus(editText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Successfully Posted");
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Died", e);
            }
        }
    }.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "onClicked");

}
```

When I run it, it reaches just the first Log i.e `Log.d(TAG, "hay i am working till here");` I can't find out what the problem is.

Comment: but what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to access the ui thread via a non ui thread with this line in your code

```
twitter.setStatus(editText.getText().toString());
```

As `edittext.getText()` should be accessed/called on ui thread.

Instead use an  handler on ui thread to accomplish your needs.

```
Handler tweethandler=new Handler(getMainLooper());
```

tweethandler .post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){

```
           try {
                Log.d(TAG, "hay i reached till here");
                twitter = new Twitter("student", "password");
                twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
                twitter.setStatus(editText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Successfully Posted");
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Died", e);
            }
}

});
```

Comment: Sorry for such bad formatting as I am posting it via mobile.

Comment: tried this but this error seems to be killing me let me post the whole thing and I tried this earlier on a ui thread ...

Comment: So whats happening now?

Comment: there is an error in front of handle and even after importing the package that doesn't go could you tell do I have to import something extra in order to use a handle

Comment: Replace the Handler.post to tweethandler.post

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "hay i am not working");
        Handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "hay i reached till here");
                    twitter = new Twitter("student", "password");
                    twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
                    twitter.setStatus(editText.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully Posted");
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Died", e);
                }
            }

        });
        Log.d(TAG, "onClicked");

    }
```